# redirect to default (home) page after login in jsf2.2 and primefaces

Tags: jsf, redirect, jsf-2, primefaces, spring-security

Using JSf2.2 with primefaces 3.4, could not redirect to home page which is my default url of application.

if I am at the one of the view(page) in my application using JSF mvc .when i stop the server and restart it and enter the existing url (or the url where my app at the moment) then my app redirect to login page ,which is done by spring security .now when i logged in again getting redirected to the view from where i came to the login page.I have checked the `javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD` in my `web.xml` it is mentioned client .what is the problem it should be redirect to defaultUrl page i.e home.xhtml . Do jsf store the previous view if we do not get properly logged out ?or some other issue kindly tell me

Comment: As far as I can see that's not a JSF matter. That's a matter of your spring-security and web filter configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not related to JSF / Primefaces as already indicated. Its due to spring security configuration.

You can control this behavior by setting either true / false for 'always-use-default-target' attribute of  tag.

Example 1:

In this example after successfull login it would always invoke /success action, irrespective of which page you initiated the action

```
        <form-login default-target-url="/success" always-use-default-target="true" />
```

Example 2:

In this example after successfull login it would show the page where you initiated the action.

```
        <form-login default-target-url="/success" always-use-default-target="false" />
```

Comment: thanks a lot ..i was missing the alwaysusedefaulttargeturl. thnaks .